How to change legedn text charts to custom text arabic?
I work on crystal report I face issue I can't change text legend to Arabic text
so how to fix that issue please ?
so legend text beside color i need to change to custom text Arabic .
Exactly I make right click - chart expert - Data - show values 
I need to change 
Sum of CountPoints 
to
اجمالى النقاط

How to change legend text to Arabic

Would you like to change the legend during export? I.e Have latin characters in the chart, and change them to arabic during exporting?
If yes, then you are using built-in exporting options, here is the API option to update the chart just for exporting: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions
Additionally, have a look at the internationalization page in the docs with Arabic chart included: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/internationalization
